# Hide 'm' from git bash windows

Tags: php, shell, git-bash, laravel-artisan, windows-shell

I am querying in database via Tinker in Git Bash windows shell but the output result with time makes me unreadable(actually hard to read) the data.

Is there any way I can hide the running time?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Those running time makes me unreadable!]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The windows CMD prompt term does not interpret ANSI escape sequences.

You can either:

- try and use **[ansicon](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon)**
- or desactivate colors (use git config --global to desactivate them in all repos)

  ```
  git config --global color.ui false
  ```

The OP points to an alternative cmd wrapper: cmder.net.

Comment: Good point. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

The windows 10 cmd now *does* support ANSI colours.

If you are getting carriage return (^M) errors, the solution to this the following:

```
git config --global core.whitespace cr-at-eol
```